# Create directories from a json

Tags: python, json, api

I am working with a list of nested dictionaries loaded into a public Singapore [API](https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images) that automatically updates the data every 15 seconds. First, I am only extracting the nested data I need with the  `extract_values` function. Nevertheless, my main goal is to create one directory with 87 directories of each `camera id`. Then store the `image` property in the correspondent directory of each `camera id`.

This is a part of the `JSON`

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-06-12T00:56:28+08:00",
      "cameras": [ {
          "timestamp": "2020-06-12T00:55:28+08:00",
          "image": "https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2020/06/ce03a29a-7c9e-4e08-aadb-2afcc25db586.jpg",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 1.323604823,
            "longitude": 103.8587802
          },
          "camera_id": "1701",
          "image_metadata": {
            "height": 480,
            "width": 640,
            "md5": "75c9ab0b027e5e8aca9de09ef0d1b7b1"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "2020-06-12T00:55:28+08:00",
          "image": "https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2020/06/ee537eb0-c7dd-474e-88a2-2615df74d28a.jpg",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 1.34355015,
            "longitude": 103.8601984
          },
          "camera_id": "1702",
          "image_metadata": {
            "height": 480,
            "width": 640,
            "md5": "1de3dfc757a5f79d137769e0c5fe75ef"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "2020-06-12T00:55:28+08:00",
          "image": "https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2020/06/e3840170-d8d5-41fd-8cdd-c6afcea96249.jpg",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 1.28569398886979,
            "longitude": 103.837524510188
          },
          "camera_id": "1704",
          "image_metadata": {
            "height": 480,
            "width": 640,
            "md5": "9cfd60fd0025b2ef6ee44177d50ad892"
          }
        },.....]
    }
  ],
  "api_info": {
    "status": "healthy"
  }
}
```

Here's my code

```
import json 
import requests


"""path = "C:/Users/Issstezac1/Desktop" """
endpoint = "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images"

"""response from API URL"""
get_req = requests.get(endpoint)

"""Transform json input to python objects""" 
data = json.loads(get_req.text)

##Prints all the json data
##print(data.get('items'))

def extract_values(obj, key):
    """Pull all values of the specified key from nested JSON."""
    arr = []

    def extract(obj, arr, key):
        """Recursively search for values of key in JSON tree."""
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for k, v in obj.items():
                if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                    extract(v, arr, key)
                elif k == key:
                    arr.append(v)
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for item in obj:
                extract(item, arr, key)
        return arr

    results = extract(obj, arr, key)
    return results

names = extract_values(data, 'camera_id')
print(names)
```

Could somebody guide me on how to achieve this? Any further help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple actually. *os* module allow us to run operations on system base. You just need a loop for handing all of cameras, create a dictionary for data if not exists and then download the image inside this dictionary. I just created a simple example for your endpoind/data.

```
import os
import ntpath
import shutil
import requests

endpoint = "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images"
data = requests.get(endpoint).json()

output_data_path = "./output_data"

if not os.path.exists(output_data_path): # check for is directory exists
    os.mkdir(output_data_path) # create the directory if not exists

for record in data["items"][0]["cameras"]:
    camera_id = record["camera_id"]
    image_location = record["image"]
    image_name = ntpath.basename(image_location)

    if not os.path.exists(f"{output_data_path}/{camera_id}"):
        os.mkdir(f"{output_data_path}/{camera_id}")
    
    image_data = requests.get(image_location, stream=True) # get the source of image
    with open(f"{output_data_path}/{camera_id}/{image_name}", 'wb') as image_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(image_data.raw, image_file) # write the source into a file

    print("Downloaded an image for camera id:", camera_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a method of creating directories, you can use os.mkdir()